# Prove $0\le ab+bc+ca-abc\le2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

A question asks

> Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative reals such that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$$
> Prove that$$0\le ab+bc+ca-abc\le2$$

The lower bound can be proven as follows:

If $a,b,c>1$, then $$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc>4$$

This implies that at least one of $a,b,c$ is less than or equal to $1$, and we can assume WLOG that $a\le1$. Then,
$$ab+bc+ca-abc=a(b+c)+bc(1-a)\ge0$$

For the upper bound, I had the idea of treating $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$ as a quadratic in $a$ but don't see any way to proceed from there. Please only give me hints!

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes it does! How does one locate such questions btw? I ask because this is twice in a row I have asked a question previously answered and I don't wish to clog up the site.

Comment: [Approach zero search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2%2Babc%3D4%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24ab%2Bbc%2Bca-abc%5Cle%202%24&p=1)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If one of $a,b,c$ is zero or two of them are equal, the inequality holds (almots) trivially.

Consider the function $ f(a,b,c) = ab+bc+ca-2abc $, with $a,b,c\ge 0, g(a,b,c) = 1$, where $g(a,b,c) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + abc$. The domain is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so $f$ must admit maximum. Assume the maximum is strictly larger than $2$, then it is taken in the interior of the domain, and $a,b,c$ are pairwisely distinct. Thus we can apply Lagrange's multiplier to get
\begin{equation}
\nabla f + \lambda \nabla g  = 0.
\end{equation}
Notice that $\partial_a g = 2a + bc > 0$, so we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{a+c -ac}{2b+ac} = \frac{b+c-bc}{2a+bc},
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
(a-b)(2a+2b+2c-2ac-2bc+c^2) = 0
\end{equation}
and two similar equations. Since we assumed $a,b,c$ are pairwisely distinct, we yield
\begin{equation}
a^2 - 2ac- 2ab = b^2 - 2bc -2ba
\end{equation}
or $a+b-2c = 0$. Then we have $a = b = c$ for sure, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

> $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4, a, b, c:$ non-negative. Prove that $0\leq ab+bc+ca-abc \leq 4.$

\begin{align}
&a, b, c: \text{non-negative.} \\
& \text{You found that }a \leq 1 \text{ or } b \leq 1 \text{ or } c \leq 1.\\
\Rightarrow  \; & 1 \leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}. \\
\therefore \; &  abc \leq ab+bc+ca, 0 \leq ab+bc+ca-abc. \\
\ \\
& (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \geq 0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca \geq 0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & a^2+b^2+c^2+abc-ab-bc-ca-abc \geq 0. \\
\Rightarrow \; & 4 = a^2+b^2+c^2+abc \geq ab+bc+ca+abc \geq ab+bc+ca-abc.
\end{align}

Comment: It is $\dots\le2$ not $4$. Anyways, nice try!